# How to delete two dynamically generated div blocks with different ids and same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Information:** I am trying to build a multiple To-Do List app. On clicking the create button a wrapper class is created in the side panel which consist of class=item (user i/p) and delete icon (fa.fa.trash). Also there is a div block with class=todolistblock created in the middlepanel for every item created in the side panel. The parent class of this todolistblock is also wrapper class.

**Expected o/p:** On clicking the delete icon the corresponding wrapper class in the side panel(item & delete icon) and wrapper class in middle panel (todolistblock) should be deleted. I am generating a different dynamic id for every wrapper class created.

**Current o/p:** It only deletes the wrapper class in the side panel and doesn't do anything to the wrapper class in the middle panel despite them having same corresponding  dynamic id.

Please let me know where am I going wrong. Also is this code efficient?

```js
var maxvalue = 9; //to restrict the number of list items created
var count = 0; //to count the number of list items created
var listitem = '<div class="item">'; //every item i/p by user is in class item
var deleteicon = '<div class="fa fa-trash">'; //delete icon
var todolistblock = '<div class="todolistblock">'; //a block created in middlepanel when creating a list
var i = 1; //to give a unique id to each wrapper div
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#createlistbutton').click(function() {
    var container = '<div class="wrapper" id="' + i + '">'; //each wrapper div has a different id
    i++; //increment the counter
    var toAdd = $('input[name=newlistitem]').val(); //i/p from user
    if (count < maxvalue) {
      $('.categories').append(container + listitem + toAdd + '</div>' + deleteicon + '</div>' + '</div>'); //dynamic adding item
      $('.middlepanel').append(container + todolistblock + '</div>' + '</div>'); //adding a div block in middlepanel
      count += 1;
    } else {
      alert("Not more than 9 list can be created");
    }
  });

  $('main').on('click', ".fa.fa-trash", function() {
    var wrapid = $('.wrapper').attr("id"); //getting the unique id of wrapper class with corresponding delete icon
    $('#' + wrapid).remove(); //delete wrap class with the same id in side & middle panel when clicked on deleteicon
    count -= 1;
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  /**background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);**/
  background-color: #b9d2d4;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/45-degree-fabric-dark.png");
  width: 100%;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  margin: 18 0 0 10;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #303030;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 15;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: None;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

footer p {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #303030;
}

.sidepanel {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: white;
}

.createinputlist {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#createlistbutton {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #303030;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa.fa-trash {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.categories {
  position: inherit;
  max-height: 80%;
}

.chatpanel {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80%;
  background-color: white;
}

#tempmsg {
  margin-top: 40%;
}

.middlepanel {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80%;
  width: 50%;
}

.todolistblock {
  height: 100%;
  position: inherit;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Python Flask App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src-animation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <h3>PYTHON FLASK APP</h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="sidepanel">
      <div class="createinputlist">
        <input type="text" name="newlistitem" />
        <button id="createlistbutton">Create List</button>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="categories">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="middlepanel">
    </div>

    <div class="chatpanel">
      <p id="tempmsg">Chat Panel<br/>Coming soon</p>
    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>COPYRIGHT &copy 2017 PowerSoft</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: on clicking the delete icon it should delete the wrapper class from both the side as well as middle panel with the corresponding id. Right now it only deletes the wrapper class (item & delete icon) of side panel and the middle panel block with class todolistblock (red color) remains as it is

Comment: I'm I'm reading correctly, you are giving two `div` tags the same id and then trying to use an id selector `#` to find and delete both of them.  That's generally not recommended (duplicate id).  I suspect jQuery is only returning the first matching div, or otherwise not liking the duplicate id.  Can you try using a prefix or suffix for the different list ids so that this isn't a duplicate id which is not valid html?

Comment: There is a problem in my code, I see it now. Can't use the same id for two elements, completely overlooked it. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### id is unique to each page, if you have id used in this panel, the same id won't selected at another panel, make sure you create a unique id for each element.

(improvement, you could use class name instead of id like `class="todo_1"` or `class="todo_2"` etc)

```js
var maxvalue=9; //to restrict the number of list items created
var count = 0; //to count the number of list items created
var listitem = '<div class="item">'; //every item i/p by user is in class item
var deleteicon = '<div class="fa fa-trash">'; //delete icon
var todolistblock = '<div class="todolistblock">'; //a block created in middlepanel when creating a list
var i = 1; //to give a unique id to each wrapper div
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#createlistbutton').click(function(){
    var container = '<div class="wrapper" id="'+i+'">'; //each wrapper div has a different id
    var containerTodo = '<div class="wrapper" id="todo'+i+'">'; 
    i++; //increment the counter
   var toAdd = $('input[name=newlistitem]').val(); //i/p from user
    if(count<maxvalue) {
     $('.categories').append(container + listitem +toAdd + '</div>' + deleteicon + '</div>' +'</div>');//dynamic adding item
        $('.middlepanel').append(containerTodo + todolistblock + toAdd + '</div>' + '</div>');//adding a div block in middlepanel
        count +=1;
    } else {
      alert("Not more than 9 list can be created");
    }      
  });  
   
  $('main').on('click',".fa.fa-trash", function(){
    var thisId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $('#'+thisId).remove();//delete wrap class with the same id in side & middle panel when clicked on deleteicon
    $('#todo'+thisId).remove();
    count -= 1;   
  });
  
});
```

```css
*{  margin:0;
 padding:0;
 }

body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  font-family: "Times New Roman","Open Sans",sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
 /**background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f06, yellow);**/ 
  background-color: #b9d2d4;
  background-image: url("https://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/45-degree-fabric-dark.png");
  width:100%;
}

h3{
  color:white;
  margin: 18 0 0 10;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-bar{
  height: 10%;
  background-color:#303030;
}
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
  margin-right:15;
  padding:0;
  float:right;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li{
  float:left;
  margin-top:5;
  
}

li a{
  display:block;
  text-decoration:None;
  padding: 8px;
  color:#ffffff;
   padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align:center;
}

li a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}

footer p{
   margin-top:25px;
   }

footer{
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:10%;
   width:100%;
   color:#ffffff;
   background:#303030;}
   

   
.sidepanel{
   width:25%;
   float:left;
   text-align:center;
   height:80%;
   background-color:white;
  }

.createinputlist{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
   
}

#createlistbutton{
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#303030;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
 }

input[type=text]{
  width:60%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.wrapper{
  text-align:center;
  
}
.item{
  border: 1px solid #303030;
  background-color:lightcyan;
  border-radius:10px;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  display:inline-block;
  width:90%;
  cursor:pointer;
  
}

.fa.fa-trash{
  display:inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.categories{
  position:inherit;
  max-height:80%;
}

.chatpanel{
   width:25%;
   float:right;
   text-align:center;
   height:80%;
   background-color:white;
  }

#tempmsg{
  margin-top:40%;
  
}
  
.middlepanel{
  display:inline-block;
  height:80%;
  width:50%;
}

.todolistblock{
  height:100%;
  position:inherit;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Python Flask App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="src-animation.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

  <body>
  <header>
  <div class="nav-bar">
    <h3>PYTHON FLASK APP</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </header>
  
    <main>
  <div class="sidepanel">
    <div class="createinputlist">
    <input type="text" name="newlistitem"/>
       <button id="createlistbutton">Create List</button>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="categories">
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="middlepanel">
  </div>
    
  <div class="chatpanel">
    <p id="tempmsg">Chat Panel<br/>Coming soon</p>
  </div>
  </main>
    
  <footer>
    <p>COPYRIGHT &copy 2017 PowerSoft</p>
  </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This still does not seem to remove the element added to `.middlepanel`, as mentioned in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

Two elements shouldn't have the same id, but they do in your code.  [jQuery will only return the first matching element when using an id selector.](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

Since your two `div` tags have the same id, it's only ever going to delete the first matching item.  You can see this same behavior below.

Change to using different ids, or you can use class names if you need to keep the id reference the same for other purposes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var idquery = $("#child");
  alert("found " + idquery.length + " items using id query");
  var classquery = $(".child");
  alert("foudn " + classquery.length + " items using class query");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent1">
  <div id="child" class="child">
  child content
  </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
  <div id="child" class="child">
  child content
  </div>
</div>
```